# Multiple ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I have the below df

```
      var1 var2  a1    a2
1    a    b      y     z
2    b    a      z     y
3    b    b      z     z
```

created from the following code

```
help <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b", "b"), var2 = c("b", "a", "b"), a1 = c(y, z, z), a2 = c(z, y, z))
```

my intention is to create an ifelse statement where I am able to (1) replace all a1 values to 'bp' when var1 equals 'a', and (2) replace all a2 values to 'bp' when var2 equals 'a'. I do not want to change the value if var1 or var2 is not 'a'.

Is the ifelse command not the best way to solve this problem? I started doing each one manually using `help$a1[help$a1 == "a"] <- "bp"` however, this will take a bit of time as I have multiple variables and a large dataset. Any assistance would be great.

Many thanks.

Comment: How many rules for replacement do you have? My wild guess is that supplementary data sets with rules might be of help in your case, e.g. `var1.rules <- c(a=0,b=1,c=2)` and `var2.rules <- c(a=0,b=1,c=2)`

Comment: I had to edit the post slightly due to needing all character vectors. I have 60 different unique variables that need to be changed within var1 and var2... but not sure if that answers your question...

Comment: You mean that your column names look like `c('var1', 'var2', 'var3',...,'varN', 'a1', a2', 'a3', ..., 'aN')`, and you need to set value in column `varX` to 'bp' if the corresponding row in the 'aX' column is equal to 'a' for any X from 1 to N?

Comment: not sure i follow the question, but the answer below by A Webb did work... if that helps clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard subsetting. Assuming per question edit that `a1` and `a2` are of class "character", then

```
df
#  var1 var2 a1 a2
#1    a    b  y  z
#2    b    a  z  y
#3    b    d  z  z

df[,3:4][df[,1:2]=="a"]<-"bp"

df
#  var1 var2 a1 b2
#1    a    b bp  z
#2    b    a  z bp
#3    b    d  z  z
```

You can also take advantage of your naming convention for the same

```
sel<-paste0("var",1:2)
mut<-paste0("a",1:2)
df[,mut][df[,sel]=="a"]<-"bp"
```

In either case the inner part, e.g. `df[,sel]=="a"` is returning a logical matrix the same shape as `df[,sel]` (and hence the same shape as `df[,mut]`), which is `TRUE` where and only where there was an "a". The outer part, e.g. `df[,mut][...]`, uses that logical matrix to indicate the subset subject to the assignment.

Comment: A Webb can you explain what that means... I am translating that to, 'change columns 3 or 4 in df to 'bp' if columns 1 or 2 contain a'. That sound right?

Comment: @bpace The inner bit, `df[,1:2]=="a"` returns a logical matrix of the same shape as `df[,1:2]` (and hence `df[,3:4]`), which is true where and only where there was an "a". The outer bit `df[,3:4][...]` is subsetting with a logical matrix, only those entries corresponding to a `TRUE` value in the matrix are subject to the assignment.